# Half HashMap Entries getting Stored in MySQL Table

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, hashmap

I am trying to iterate my HashMap and save the values in MySQL table. The HashMap contains 60 entries however it is only storing 26 entries in the MySQL table. I have printed my HashMap and confirmed that it has 60 entries but while inserting it in the table only limited number(26) entries are getting stored which is weird.

```
public HashMap<String, Product> inserintosql() throws IOException
        {

        String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
        String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/assign";
        String USER = "root";
        String PASS = "root";

        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = null;
        try 
        {
            saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        }   
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (SAXException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        try 
        {
            saxParser.parse(new File("/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/webapps/csj/WEB-INF/ProductCatalog.xml"), handler);
        }   
        catch (SAXException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HashMap<String,Product> productList = handler.getEmpList();

        try
        {
        //conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            size=productList.size();
            String query = " insert into products (prodtype, itemId, imgname, itemName, prodCondition, retailerName, price)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            final int batchSize = 60;
            int count = 0;
            for (String key : productList.keySet() ) 
            {

                 Product con= productList.get(key);
                 pst.setString(1,con.getProducttype()); 
                 pst.setString(2,con.getId()); 
                 pst.setString(3,con.getImage());
                 pst.setString(4,con.getName());
                 pst.setString(5,con.getCondition());
                 pst.setString(6,con.getRetailer());
                 pst.setDouble(7,con.getPrice());
                 pst.addBatch();

                if (++count == batchSize)
                {
                    pst.executeBatch();
                }   

            }
            pst.executeBatch();
        }
        catch(SQLException se) 
            {
            }
        catch(Exception e) 
            {
            } 
        return productList;
        }
```

In the above code all the product data are stored in XML file which is parsed using SAX parser and stored in the HashMap 'productList'. I am iterating the hashMap and inserting the data into the MySQL table however only 26 entries out of 60 are getting stored in the MySQL table.

MySQL table Structure is

[MySQL table structure where hashmap data is being stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP7ok.png)

Snapshot of MySQL table display hashmap iterated data.

[Snapshot of MySQL table display 26 entries received from the hashmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZzKf.png)

Can you please help me in inserting the entire hashmap in the table or pint point why I am on the wrong track.

Comment: this is you trouble `catch(SQLException se) 
            {
            }
        catch(Exception e) 
            {
            } `  **log** your exceptions

Comment: and roll up the exceptions into one try catch block

Comment: Also, if your map happens to contain a multiple of 60 entries, you will execute the last batch twice.

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace() in your empty catch'es to find out what's wrong. For example, con.getName() could be too long for the database for 36 of your objects (maybe the column's width/size is only 20 while some of the names are 21-30 chars).

Comment: Of course, I would not forgot the possibility that you don't read all the line of your XML, based on what your handler do ... are you sure your `String key` are unique ? Just check that your map is complete.

Comment: I am getting error "Data too long for column 'itemName' at row 1". Though my itemId is defined as varchar(60) and data which I am trying to add in the table are less than 20 chars in size.

Comment: It worked guys. I have just changed the data type to longtext from varchar and now all the data is getting inserted into the table. Thank you guys for your help.